# Session array element is somehow overwritten

Tags: php, session

A have a problem with PHP application, that I'm working on. Main page which consists of some elements has specificaly one which handles sign in form. In that file/element if the sign in button is pressed I try to sign in. If there is no such user in database or no information was inserted ( this is treated same way ) I set specific value for a specific key in sessions array and till the end of the application I do `var_dump` of `$_SESSION` array to see it contents. Till the end of the application everything is fine, but in the header when the page loads again after first line which is `session_start` I `var_dump` `$_SESSION` array again and this specific index already has diferent value. I just can't understand where it is set.

Sorry, for non-code explanation, but since it's a commercial application I can't provide any.

**UPDATE:**

*index.php* - first line
`require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/header.php' );`

*header.php* - first lines
`session_start();`
`var_dump( $_SESSION );`

*loginForm.php* - place where value is set.
`$_SESSION['lverifier'] = 3;`
`var_dump( $_SESSION );`

*index.php* - last lines
`require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/footer.php' );`
`var_dump( $_SESSION );`

Comment: You can't provide code, even not code that's stripped down to the bare minimum which exhibits this behaviour?

Comment: Sorry for nonexistent answer, but since it's an invisible application, I can't provide one. :-p

Comment: But seriously, we'll try with whatever you _can_ provide. More is better.

Comment: You can make a testcase. It doesn't matter whether the original code is proprietary. Your organisation has not copyrighted basic use of built-in PHP functions.

Comment: Added some code. @Marcel Korpel seriously is this comment really worth 6 points? ^o)

Comment: _loginForm.php_ does not perform `session_start()`.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal If this is a question, then no.

Comment: I can't vote on my own comments, so you should ask that question to someone else. But I think it deserves that many, as you ask a question about a specific problem you perceive, but expect us to ‘guess’ your code... Really, do you expect us to have a crystal ball? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: I can't understand where it is set either.

Comment: @Eugene: It was not a question (questions end in question marks, like `?`). It was an observation. You did not start the session before writing to a session variable. This is a mistake.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal This is quite a strange observation. Did you see the code, that I added? Isn't it clearly said, that first lines in header file are `session_start()`... and only after I set some value for some index in `$_SESSIONS` array?

Comment: @Eugene: So does _loginForm.php_ include _header.php_? Your pseudo-code doesn't say that.

Comment: But you just confirmed that *loginForm.php* doesn't perform `session_start()` before `$_SESSION['lverifier'] = 3;`. So you *do* include *header.php* in *loginForm.php* before `$_SESSION['lverifier'] = 3;`?

Comment: @Marcel Correct. Sorry for misleading you. Forgot to mansion, that `loginForm.php` is also included in `index.php`, but later then the header where `session_start()` is called.

Comment: This really makes no sense to me, it should work as expected. Can you provide a real, working test case that exhibits this issue? Just one short PHP script would suffice (where you include relevant parts of your code in it).

Comment: Thank you all, but I think, that some other code from application was intervening. Due to that this issue did occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to issue `session_start()` *before* you can access session variables:

> When a visitor accesses your site, PHP will check automatically (if [session.auto_start](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start) is set to 1) or on your request (explicitly through [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) or implicitly through [session_register()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php)) whether a specific session id has been sent with the request. If this is the case, the prior saved environment is recreated.

[[source]](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)